# Removing sections of a text file given a specific value for a character

Tags: python

I have a text file. The text file is very large, about 6 million lines, but I need only a relatively small subsection of that file.

The file is divided into chunks of about 1200 characters. I need to see whether characters 921-922 of each chunk correspond to five different numbers. If they don't, I need the entire chunk deleted.

How do I go about doing this?

Comment: I'd start with a short file, just 4 or 5 chunks and try to write some code. Depending on how often you expect matches it might make most sense to make a new file to write and append only the matching chunks.

Comment: We need more information. How are they divided into chunks of 1200 characters exactly? Is each line a chunk? Is each chunk segmented by newline characters?

Comment: Note that just because it has a lot of lines doesn't mean it's going to be memory intensive. Python's file I/O is lazily loaded - you only get the next line when you ask for it. You don't have to load the whole file into memory - at any given time, you can have just one line loaded into memory.

Comment: Finally - this may also be an ideal job for the little-known C-descended function that somehow got roped into Python: [`seek()`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/file_seek.htm).

Answer (score 0):

I think simplest answer is - to open another temporary file for writing. Read 1200 characters at a time (read in an array and directly compare the bytes at offset you mention). If your condition is true, write to the temp file or else do nothing. Rename the temp file to your file once you are done reading the file. Something along those lines.